# Powershell's -match and punctuation

Tags: string, powershell, match

I'm trying to write a function in Powershell that tests if a string ends with punctuation. Right now that method looks like this:

```
function ends_in_punctuation #Tests whether or not a word ends in punctuation
{
    param([string]$WordToTest) #Takes string to check ending of
    $CharToCheck = $WordToTest[$WordToTest.Length - 1] #Getting last character of string
    $Punctuation = ".?!" #Ending punctuation in english
    If($Punctuation -match $CharToCheck) #If last character is punctuation
    {
        $true #return true
    }
    Else
    {
        $false #return false
    }
}
```

It works great if the word ends with a period or exclamation point but when the word ends with a question mark it throws this error

```
[ERROR] parsing "?" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing.
[ERROR] At D:\...\PigLatin.ps1:24 char:5
[ERROR] +     If($Punctuation -match $CharToCheck) #If last character is punctu ...
[ERROR] +        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ERROR]     + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
[ERROR]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException
[ERROR]
```

And have no idea why. I'm new to PowerShell so any help I can get would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Isn't that `-match` inverted? Don't you want your pattern on the right-hand side? Alternatively wouldn't an array and `-contains` work better here?

Comment: Your problem is that the right-hand side of `-match` is a regular expression and `?` is a metacharacter for that and it can't stand alone without being escaped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your operands are reversed. `-match` takes a string (or collection) on the left side and a regular expression on the right side.

Furthermore, since `-match` takes a regex, the string you have there and try to match, is horribly wrong and won't do what you want at all. Currently it means »match any string that contains an exclamation mark, preceded by any character (but even if there is no character, it's okay)«.

Your regex should use a character class for the punctuation; this also neatly solves the problem of `.` and `?` being special characters in regular expressions:

```
[.?!]
```

So all in all you probably need something like the following:

```
$CharToCheck -match '[.?!]'
```

Another option would be to check whether the last character of the string is in your punctuation string:

```
$Punctuation.Contains($CharToCheck)
```

or

```
$CharToCheck -in [char[]]$Punctuation
```

Or to use a regex match for the whole string (the regex here is anchored to the end of the string):

```
$WordToTest -match '[.?!]$'
```

Getting the last character can also be done with

```
$WordToTest[-1]
```

PowerShell is a bit nicer here than C#.

Comment: This fixed my problem, thank you so much for the code and detailed explanation!